# Copiar hoja de documento Google Docs en otra documento

Tags: google-apps-script, google-documentos

Estoy intentando copiar una hoja de un documento Google Docs en otro documento, pero soy incapaz de hacerlo. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Estoy intentando con el objeto `Document` y `Body` pero no consigo, lo máxímo que he conseguido es copiar el contenido pero sin formato:

```
bodyReport.setText(copyBody.getText());
```

Estoy pensando en hacerlo manualmente y es recorriendo los elementos e ir dándole formato pero claro, es bastante laborioso.

Fuente de la función:

```
function createReport() {
  try {
    if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') { 
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No existe definida en TEMPLATE_ID la plantilla  del informe");
      return
    }
    var docCopy = DocumentApp.openById(TEMPLATE_ID),
        docReport = DocumentApp.create(REPORT_FILE_NAME),
        bodyCopy = docCopy.getBody(),
        bodyReport = docReport.getBody()
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
        numberOfRows = activeSheet.getLastRow()

    var activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns).getValues();
    for (var row = 1; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
      bodyCopy.replaceText('%' + fieldTematica + '%', activeRow[row][columnTematica]);
      bodyCopy.replaceText('%' + fieldImpacto + '%', activeRow[row][columnImpacto]);
      bodyCopy.replaceText('%' + fieldUrgencia + '%', activeRow[row][columnUrgencia]);
      bodyCopy.replaceText('%' + fieldAreaCoordinadora + '%', activeRow[row][columnAreaCoordinadora]);
      bodyCopy.replaceText('%' + fieldActuacionCurso + '%', activeRow[row][columnActuacionCurso]);
      bodyCopy.appendPageBreak(); 
    }

    //bodyReport.appendParagraph(bodyCopy.getParagraphs());
    bodyReport.setText(copyBody.getText());
    docCopy.saveAndClose();
    docReport.saveAndClose();
    //var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  

    //copyFile.setTrashed(true)  
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Se ha creado un nuevo PDF en su unidad Google Drive')

  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log("ERROR in function createPdf \r\nMessage: " + e.message + "\r\nFile gs: " + e.fileName + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber)
    Logger.log("\r\nUser: " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + ", Date: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMMdd'_'HH:mm:ss"));
  } 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mariano por la respuesta, te he incluido el fuente. Perdona pero soy nobel en stackoverflow.

Comment: Buenas @Mariano, al final lo he conseguido con la función que he incluido en la pregunta, me ha funcionado bastante bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la siguiente función me ha servido para lo que quería, la he obtenido del siguiente hilo de stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987101/how-to-copy-content-and-formatting-between-google-docs/19987972#19987972.

```
function copyDoc() {
  try {
    var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById(TEMPLATE_ID).getBody();
    var targetDoc =  DocumentApp.create(REPORT_FILE_NAME);
    var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();
    for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
      var body = targetDoc.getBody();
      var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        body.appendParagraph(element);
      } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        body.appendTable(element);
      } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        body.appendListItem(element);
      } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
        body.appendImage(element);
      }
      //    ...add other conditions (headers, footers...
    }
    //targetDoc.saveAndClose();
    return targetDoc;
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log("ERROR in function copyDoc \r\nMessage: " + e.message + "\r\nFile gs: " + e.fileName + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber)
    Logger.log("\r\nUser: " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + ", Date: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMMdd'_'HH:mm:ss"));
  } 
}
```

Comment: Sigue pareciendo una enumeración larga... ¿no esxite ya una finción de "saveAs" para el doc, que puedas invocar? Nunca usé Google Docs programáticamente, pero empezaría por ahí.

Comment: @Richi: ¿el código es tuyo o lo obtuviste de alguien más? De no ser tuyo deberías realizar a atribución apropiada, de lo contrario sería un caso de plagio.

Comment: Perdona @Rubén, es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow y no era mi intención atribuirme la solución, he incluido en la respuesta el enlace al hilo donde he encontrado la solución.

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro, intente con alguna función de ese tipo o incluso buscando algún copy en el body o similar pero no encontré nada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema. Tenía un documento plantilla y quería hacer una copia para sustituir después las etiquetas {{etiqueta}}. Al final lo conseguí con:

```
var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy(fileName, folder);
```

Por ejemplo:

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').makeCopy('Contrato de ' + client.name); // Copia plantilla
  var bodyNewDoc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId()).getBody();
```

Huelga decir que soy un aficionado y un chapuzas. Pero me funciona y el código es mucho más corto.

Answer (score 0):

Código de Juan S Guzman

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBKyTIzn-0NAT-tXGHUCCMA

```
//identificaciones de carpetas y documentos
var plantillaID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var ficherosID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
//conecto con la plantilla
var archivoPlantilla = DriveApp.getFileById(plantillaID);
//conecto con la carpeta donde quiero dejar el documento nuevo
var carpetaFicheros = DriveApp.getFolderById(ficherosID);
//creo una nueva subcarpeta en la carpeta ficheros
var nuevaCarpeta = carpetaFicheros.createFolder("nombre nueva carpeta");
//Crear Documento nuevo desde la plantilla y lo dejo en la nueva carpeta
var copiaArchivoPlantilla = archivoPlantilla.makeCopy(nuevaCarpeta);
//obtengo la ID del nuevo documento
var copiaID = copiaArchivoPlantilla.getId();
//genero el nombre del nuevo documento
var nombreDocumento = "Nombre del documento nuevo";
//le pongo el nuevo nombre
copiaArchivoPlantilla.setName(nombreDocumento);
//Tambien puedo abrir el nuevo documento por su ID
var doc =DocumentApp.openById(copiaID);
//y luego asignarle el nombre
doc.setName(nombreDocumento);
```

Comment: No copies y pegues un código, por favor, lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), considera explicar cómo tu código puede ayudar